# Using AWK or Sed how can I remove trailing carriage return and a line feeds before first txt

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Using AWK or Sed, how can I remove carriage returns and line feeds from the start of a file before first txt.

Before

```
 TOP OF FILE - Carriage returns and line feeds before txt


 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <fredBaa version="1.2" properties="2.8" Baa="2.13 r1665067">
  <hashTree>...
```

After

```
TOP OF FILE - No Carriage returns and line feeds before txt
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <fredBaa version="1.2" properties="2.8" Baa="2.13 r1665067">
  <hashTree>...
```

Comment: Are there actual carriage returns at the start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is:

```
awk 'NF{f=1}f' file
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
awk '/</{a=1}a' file
```

or to remove all leading lines until the one that has a non-blank character:

```
awk '/[^[:space:]]/{a=1}a' file
```

Comment: Does space contain carriage returns ?

Answer (score 1):

does this work for you?

```
sed '0,/./{/./!d}' file
```

Comment: won't sed see a carriage return as a character ?

Comment: @123 what does your test tell?